# Editing the Microsoft Security Essentials context-menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, dll, ms-security-essentials

As all MSE users would know, the context-menu item that it adds to Explorer is really long, with one whole sentence "Scan with Microsoft Security Essentials...". Is there a way to edit this and shorten it?

I figured out the the file `shellext.dll` is responsible for registering the context menu. I used [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) to edit the DLL and changed the string table entry from `Scan with ($BrandName)` to `Scan with MSE`. But it still won't change. I've also tried de-registering the DLL and then registering it again. No luck!

Any ideas? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Silly question, did you restart after applying the change to shellext.dll?

Comment: Of course I did! No change though :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to successfully rename the MSE context-menu entry by editing:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\en-us\shellext.dll.mui"
```

The change took effect once I logged out and then logged back in.

Answer (score 1):

You could try both nirsoft's [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html). If you don't like using apps for this, you could check out this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/).

Comment: Those tools will certainly allow the MSE context menu item to be disabled (i.e. removed from the list) but they aren't capable of renaming the item as requested in the question since that's handled in the DLL itself.